# Scatter-plot in chart.js: How to show legends only for specific points

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've implemented a scatter plot. The Y-axes has these labels: Classification, type-1-defect and type-2-defect. What I am plotting is a set of pieces of different types and each one of them can present no defects or present a type-1-defect or a type-2-defect.

I don't want to show a legend for every single point of the chart. I only want to show a legend for each type of piece shown in the line Classification.

For example, if I have 10 pieces: 4 are type1, 3 are type2 and 3 are type3, by default, the legends shown are one for each point in the chart. What I want is show only 3 legends: one for each kind of piece found. Is there a way to implement that? Thanks in advance.

```
Classification   T1 T1 T1 T1 T2 T2 T2 T3 T3 T3  
type-1-defect    +  +  +     +        +     +  
type-2-defect       +  +  +  +      +       +
```

Legends shown by default:

```
T1 T1 T1 T1 T2 T2 T2 T3 T3 T3 + + + + + + + + + + + +
```

Legends that I want to be shown:

```
T1 T2 T3
```

Comment: please add the code you tried.